# Putting an element directly after text that may/may not be truncated

Tags: html, css

So I want something like this:

```
Hello [element]
```

but also this case:

```
Hello blahblahblah... [element]
```

floating the element right does this, which I do not want:

```
Hello                 [element]
Hello blahblahblah... [element]
```

EDIT:

the html I tried was this:

```
<h3 id="container">
  <span>[element]</span>
  <a>dynamic text</a>
</h3>
```

css:

```
span{
  float: right;
}

#container {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Another problem is [element] could be of variable length.  I want to truncate the a tag so that it fits all of [element] and put it all on one line.  I know that might've just made the question much harder...

EDIT 2:

Realized it wasn't clear that I want the container h3 to be of fixed max width.  So basically if the a tag and span's combined width is greater than that max width, the span will put the truncation location to the left. Like so:

the string is: Hello World

So it could look like this in that case:

Hello Worl...[small el]

Hell...[bigger span el]

Ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just place the span after the anchor?

Comment: What ends up happening with that is that it becomes part of the overflow, since the css is on the container.  Right now, I'm playing around with moving the css to the a tag.

Comment: what kind of [element] is that? if it's an image or so you can use `:after`

Comment: It could include a lot of markup, such as multiple images, they are a collection of badges essentially.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/ZeaHA/

Comment: @prashn64 hey I was going thru this question, would like a solution using javascript as well? If not, is there any reason you don't want to use javascript? To lazy to answer right now... do let me know if JS is okay, will take some time tomorrow with working fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated Idea

This is a refined version of my original idea below, but attempts to create your fixed width of container and general look that you mentioned in the chat using an extra wrapping `div`. The only way I see that this could work purely by css is for *you to know before hand what your maximum width of your "badge" area **could** be*, and then set your `max-width` of the text area to be the width of the container minus that potential maximum width of the badge area. Here is the revised code below and [**fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tnPkF/44/), where I am assuming a `200px` container, with a maximum of `100px` badge area width. You will end up with some of the text being cut off "prematurely" (as in, it would appear that it could go wider, but we are limiting it to a certain space; see the third line in the fiddle).

**HTML**

```
<h3 class="container">
  <div>   
  <span>[elem]</span>
  <a>dynamic text</a>
  </div>
</h3>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 200px; /* this defines your right edge */
  background-color: cyan;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container > div {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: .1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container a {
  display: block; 
    /* the following assumes the span "badge" area is 100px max, 
       so it is 200px - 100px = 100px in width */ 
  max-width: 100px;  
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;   
}
```

### Original Idea

Perhaps this would work.

```
.container {
  float: left; /* this collapses the container around the 'a' tag */
  position: relative; /* this is going to position the 'span' */
  padding-right: .1em; /* gap to element 'span' */
  white-space: nowrap; 
}

.container span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%; /* push behind 'a' tag */
  white-space: nowrap; /* keep this from wrapping */
}

.container a {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100px; /* set your max width for the 'a' tag only */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;   
}
```

[**See a fiddle example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tnPkF/21/)

Comment: Close, but imagine if the a tags have the same width, but one of them has a larger span next to it.  I want the container element to be of a fixed max width, let's say 200.  So if the span and a tag have a width of more than 200px, the a tag would truncate.  As the span got bigger the truncation would show less and less text, basically being pushed to the left.  That's not clear in the question I realized, so I will edit it.

Comment: @prashn64--is there a max-width to the [element(s)] in the `span`, or could it take over the entire width of the `h3`?

Comment: In theory yes Scott, but it won't actually be wide enough to do that given the amount of badges I have.

Comment: @prashn64--based on your original post, it appears you also do not want a gap between the [element] and the tag (as your right float example had). If so, it seems you want the impossible. You want right alignment on the [elements] (no matter width), truncation of long text in `a` tag, but no gap ever between the two if `a` is short (at least, that is how I interpret it). Which is more important, no center gap for short `a` text or right alignment of the badges?

Comment: what if the width of the [element] was set to be the remaining width of the h3, for example, if the width of the h3 was set to 200px, and the a tag had a width of 100px, the [element], regardless of contents, would get a width of 100px.  Then it can be floated right and not visually right aligned with the h3.  Is that possible in CSS, or is that only a javascript hack?

Comment: @prashn64--If you set fixed widths on the two (`a` and `span`), that is probably the easiest, but that would left align each (the text and badges) if you are not right aligning the badges (basically making 2 columns). If you want maximum text size, that is possible with right aligned badges, but may leave a gap if the text is short. I'm just trying to figure out what your ideal look is for all situations of your combinations between the `a` text and `span` badges. Let's shoot for ideal first. Give me a clear example of short and long versions of each of `a` and `span` (4 combinations).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19613/discussion-between-prashn64-and-scotts)

Comment: @prashn64--added an updated answer that gets close to what you want, but requires you to know a piece of information to which I do not know if you have that available.

Comment: Your solution is certainly close, and I now believe it is the closest it can get without javascript.  I will accept it because of that.  The problem I have with it is that it assumes the span area is of fixed width rather than variable.

Comment: Wondering if there have been new ideas in the last 1.5 years. I cannot imagine that this is impossible to solve, because - in my opinion - this is a rather basic requirement.

Comment: @AndreasEK: I am not aware of anything new. The [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) effect requires a number of factors to align for it to even take effect (block element, too narrow for text, with text not set to wrap, etc.), so that is the limiting factor. My solution here works, but only because at some point the width becomes limited (hence the need for `max-width`), which then engages the possibility of `text-overflow` to show `ellipsis` if the text is too long. I don't foresee another solution in the near future.